# Prove that $\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}\geq 27$

Tags: inequality

How can I prove $\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}\geq 27$, given that $(x+y+z)(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z})\geq 9$ and $x+y+z=1$.

I've already tried using that: $\frac{1}{x} +\frac{1}{y} +\frac{1}{z}\geq 9$ But I can't seem to manipulate that to prove the above.

Comment: The title isn't supposed to be the first line of your question.

Comment: @GitGud :I don't get it, what is wrong?

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more? What have you tried already?

Comment: @Arjang just as I said: the title isn't supposed to be the first line of your question. Effectively your 'question' is $$\text{Given that }(x+y+z)(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z})\geq 9 \text{ and }x+y+z=1 $$ which isn't a question at all.

Answer (score 8):

Cauchy-Schwarz inequality tells us that
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\right)^2 \leq 3\times \left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}\right)\qquad (\star)
\end{equation}
But the left-hand term is $\geq 9^2$, so
$$
\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2} \geq \frac{9^2}{3} = 27.
$$

---

Note that in this particular case, it very is easy to prove $(\star)$. Let
$$
A = 3 \left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}\right),\qquad B = \left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\right)^2.
$$

We need to show that $A \geq B$. Taking their difference,
\begin{align}
A - B & = \frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2} - 2\frac{1}{xy} + \frac{1}{y^2} + \frac{1}{z^2} - 2\frac{1}{yz} + \frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{x^2} - 2\frac{1}{zx}\\
& = \left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{z}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2\\
& \geq 0.
\end{align}

Comment: is one of the y's is meant  to be a z instead?

Comment: @Arjang: correction made, thanks!

Comment: I was wondering if there was a method that's not based on any "formulas",etc, such as Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @Azza: see the note in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may also try this :

Apply AM-HM inequality on the set $\{x^2,y^2,z^2\}$ :

$$\frac {x^2+y^2+z^2}{3} \geq \frac {3}{\frac {1}{x^2}+\frac {1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}}$$

$$\implies \big(x^2+y^2+z^2\big)\big({\frac {1}{x^2}+\frac {1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}}\big) \geq 9$$

$$\implies {\frac {1}{x^2}+\frac {1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}} \geq \frac{9}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\,\,\,(♦)$$

Now all that remains is to prove that $$x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq \frac{1}{3} \,\,\,(♣)$$

with the constraint that $$x+y+z=1 $$

I am assuming that you are skilled enough to prove $(♣)$. (You can use Lagrange Multipliers or some other technique.)

Plug $(♣)$ into $(♦)$ to get :

$$ {\frac {1}{x^2}+\frac {1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}}\geq \frac{9}{1/3} = 27$$

$$HENCE \,\,\,\, PROVED$$
**NOTE** : Since $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is in the denominator (♦) , the sign of (♣) flips/reverts , thus proving the desired inequality.